# HTTP port cannot triggered different endpoints simultaneously

Tags: http, ubuntu, port80

I have three workflows in Robomotion running three different endpoints with the same IP. I try to use Postman just for testing the port that running in Robomotion. But, only the workflow that running first in Robomotion can be triggered not the other. The other port got this error `404 not found`. I'm using port 80. Is it port 80 cannot be triggered simultaneously?

Below is the open port that I'm using in Robomotion.

```
1st Workflow: http://206.xxx.xx.xx:80/abc
2nd Workflow: http://206.xxx.xx.xx:80/def
3rd Workflow: http://206.xxx.xx.xx:80/ghi
```

Can anyone explain? I run this process in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Provide a minimal, working example.

Comment: what example should I provide? @Ouroborus

Comment: Something representing your code.

Comment: i dont have any code that can be shown anymore. because this is just between http in Robomotion and Postman @Ouroborus